# Jenkins pipeline and Hudson

Tags: jenkins, hudson

I'm using Jenkins and in particular pipelines. What's the difference between pipelines and Hudson jobs with multiple build steps?

Comment: Don't use Hudson - development on Hudson ceased a long time ago. A pipeline is a way to maintain your build logic in code rather than having to deal with the classic freestyle job UI, among many other things. [Pipeline tutorials](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/hello-world/#what-is-a-jenkins-pipeline)

Comment: Yes, but at the moment my company use Hudson so I would understand the difference with Jenkins pipelines

Answer (score 0):

When Kohsuke forked Jenkins from Hudson the entire developer community went with him.  Oracle's grab for Hudson and attempt to make it proprietary killed Hudson overnight.  This is well documented elsewhere. No one in their right mind should be using Hudson over Jenkins.

Hudson jobs are just freestyle jobs with a lot less functionality because Jenkins has, since forking, greatly increased the number of plugins as it had the developer community. Oracle had one guy sitting in a corner hacking on Hudson.

For one thing, Pipeline jobs allow you to version your job definitions in source control. Old school Freestyle jobs do not.  To list all the other ways Jenkins is better than Hudson would require a million monkeys writing the works of Shakespeare!